# I am not getting any value in pandas empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
x = 21
y = 93
df['abc'] = (x/y).round(decimals = 2)
df
```

But this gives me

```
| abc |
|-----|
```

Required Output is

```
| abc  |
|------|
| 0.23 |
```

Comment: `df['abc'] = [(x/y).round(decimals = 2)]`

Comment: @Nullman This cause an error, the correct way is: `[round(x/y, 2)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try `(x/y).round(decimals = 2)` , you will see that it throws an error 'float' object has no attribute 'round'. You are trying to use `round()` as a method here, which does not exist for floats. Hence you cannot insert this into the dataframe

The suggestion offered by @DavidS in the comments above works:

```
df['abc'] = round(x/y,2)
```

Numpy array and Pandas series have the round method so there's a few ways you can also do this:

```
df['abc'] = pd.Series(x/y).round(decimals=2)

import numpy as np
df['abc'] = np.array(x/y).round(decimals=2)

df['abc'] = x/y 
df = df.round(2)
```